Waiting Time after Renaming pattern files in theme/patterns folder
Waiting Time after Renaming pattern files in theme/patterns folder.
Why does it take so long to become visible after renaming? And where can I "refresh" this cache manualy?
I did cache refresh with plugins.... But it did not do anything.
Thank you in Advance!

the cache can be on the host level or managed by a plugin. edit your question to add more details about which one your question is about.
